# How to get Emacs to load Auctex using an init file in my HOME directory?

Tags: emacs, auctex

I am making the transition to Emacs from TexStudio because I can see that it's gonna really speed up things even though it's going to be a tough learning curve.

So far all my initialisation code works if it's in the `site-start.el` file. However when I put the same code in my `HOME` directory it throws the error:

```
File error: Cannot open load file, no such file or directory, auctex.el.
```

I guess that means it is reading my init file but looking for the AUCTeX package in the wrong place. How do I fix this?

Here are the relevant lines from my init file.

```lisp
;AucTex and Preview-Latex
(load "auctex.el" nil t t)
(load "preview-latex.el" nil t t)
```

Comment: How did you install AUCTeX?

Comment: Your `.emacs` file should be in your "home" directly..?

Comment: @giordano - I installed it from within emacs using M-x package-install

Comment: Actually, I just realised as soon as I set HOME directory, none of the code in my site-start.el file is executed either.

Comment: If you install AUCTeX with GNU Elpa you must not load it manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You installed AUCTeX using the [GNU Elpa](http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/auctex.html) repository, i.e. with <kbd>M-x</kbd> `package-install` <kbd>RET</kbd> `auctex` <kbd>RET</kbd>, in this case you must **not** load it "manually" in your init file, the package manager does it for you.  This is clearly explained also in the AUCTeX manual: http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#Installation

Comment: Ah you are right. I just removed the lines from site-start.el and it works fine. But then I defined a HOME variable to point towards something specific (so that I can have my own .emacs file and customize it) and then Auctex wouldn't load automatically when I open a .tex file.

Comment: Where did you define that variable? Inside or outside Emacs?  If you want to load Emacs with a different init file than the standard ones, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/17146844/2442087 instead of fiddling with environment variables.  And that's not the point of the question anyway.

Comment: I defined it outside Emacs in System Properties - Advanced - Environment variables. And yes I know, I didn't realize it was the HOME variable causing the problem until I saw your answer.

Comment: Well, unless you have a **very** good reason to do that, you should **not** change the value of `HOME`, other applications use that variable.  If you want to really move your home directory, that would not be effective anyway.  So, never change the value of `HOME`.

Comment: Right, okay I'll just put everything in the site-start.el file then.